# how to set the proxy server credentials using $mech->proxy

Tags: perl, proxy, web-scraping

I am making a scraper script.To avoid my script gettng blocked I am using a proxy service which has given me username and password(I havn't done it before).
How to implement this in my code is a problem.
I am doing

my $proxy = '64.120.237.206:8080';

$mech->proxy('http', "http://$proxy");

My problem is how and where I should set the username and password given by the proxy service provider.

Please help

Comment: I'm assuming you use WWW::Mechanize, from the "$mech" variable name?

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) class, which is the base class of WWW::Mechanize.  It will explain that you can set environment variables for the proxy username and password.

Additionally, the [lwpcook](https://metacpan.org/module/lwpcook#PROXIES) page has a section that explains how to set the username and password as part of the proxy() command.  But I don't recommend that, as putting passwords into source code is generally a bad idea.

---

2012-12-02:
create an array of proxy URL/port pairs, chose one using a the random number generator.

Comment: Thanks Jaffe ,I'll study that and let you know how it has comeup

Comment: Hi Len I am doing   $mech->proxy('http','http://64.129.222.206:8080');
$mech->credentials( 'usrname', 'pwd' );  The script is not stopping. Does it mean its working

Comment: Off the top of my head, I thought the credentials() methos was for HTTP Authentication to web servers, not proxy servers.

Comment: The best way that I've found to determine what a program is doing, is to use the debugger.  Set a break point for the HTTP fetch (get/post) and then eek at various bits of the object, like status and content.  If you have the stomach for it, you can learn a lot about how LWP works, by dumping the $mech object at various points throughout its lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks Len for the insight...but I already do use debugger(I hate using it I admit).

Comment: Hi ,I have a list of proxies that I want  to use in my script randomly.How can that be achieved?